# How to do column mapping without using minus

Tags: java, sql

I Have two tables A and A2.

```
TABLE A                      TABLE A2
-------------------   ------------------------------  
ID NAME     AGE           ID NAME      AGE
1  POOJA    18            1 POOJA      -
2  ANU      -             2 ANU        -
3  APPU      20           3 APPU       18
```

If i use minus query i am gettng output:

```
select name ,age from A MINUS select name,age from a2 ;


 name age 
------------------
    pooja 18
    appu 20
```

I Want same output without using MINUS query.

Comment: Do `NOT EXISTS` sub-query.

Comment: I Tried that.SELECT name ,age from A WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NAME,AGE FROM A2);

Comment: but i got 'no rows'

Comment: Why don't you want to use MINUS?

Comment: Rolled back to original version. Please don't invalidate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your rdbms (which you didn't specified) support multiple matching conditions in `NOT IN`, You can also use `NOT IN` as below.

```
    SELECT a.NAME
    ,a.age
FROM tableA a
WHERE (
        a.NAME
        ,coalesce(a.age, 0)
        ) NOT IN (
        SELECT b.NAME
            ,coalesce(b.age, 0)
        FROM tableB b
        );
```

**Result:**

```
NAME    AGE
---------------
POOJA   18
APPU    20
```

---

**Update 1:**

If `age = 0` need to be handled, we can use below query.

```
SELECT a.NAME
    ,a.age
FROM tableA a
WHERE (
        a.NAME
        ,coalesce(a.age, - 1)
        ) NOT IN (
        SELECT b.NAME
            ,coalesce(b.age, - 1)
        FROM tableB b
        );
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/BLZP44643)**

Comment: You're using 0 instead of null.

Comment: So what happens if there are new born babies in the tables? (With age 0.)

Comment: If we put zero instead of null i will get the same output.i just tried your demo by adding null in the place of zero.it returns APPU 20

Comment: Its not about age will be zero.some other columns if its null came,i want to identify .that is the reason i trying with null.please help

Comment: @user8709290: `APPU 20` should be returned as per your demo. If i am getting you wrong, Can you kindly edit your question and include all cases.

Comment: no.i wrote i want the same output without  using minus query.using minus query i got 2 rows u can c that in my questn

Comment: @user8709290: And i uses your sample data and produced the exact desired result using `NOT IN` as shown in demo:-)

Comment: Thank you so much.got it.Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to select rows from A where there are no matching row in A2:

```
SELECT name ,age
from A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from A2
                  where a.NAME = a2.name and
                       (A.AGE = A2.Age
                        or coalesce(A.AGE, A2.Age) is null))
```

Comment: it return the common one also.ANU ----

Comment: ANU should not come na

Comment: Right, forgot about NULL's here... Don't hang up, will edit